# r data.frame create new variable

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe with around 1.5 million rows and 5 cols. One variable (VARIABLE) is of this type NATIONALITY_YEAR (e.g. SPAIN_1998) and I want to split it in two columns, one containing the Nationality, which is the left side of the name before the underscore, and one containing the Year, right side of the underscore. I have tried with concat.split which should be the easiest way:

```
aa <- concat.split(mydata, "VARIABLE", sep = "_", drop = F)
```

but after 2 hours running it did not produce any output. I am not sure if I should leave it running for a longer period of time or if there is a non time consuming way to do this.

Any help on the issue would be very much appreciated!

Here is a reproducible (subset!) sample:

```
mydata<-  structure(list(PROVINCE = c(1L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 14L, 17L, 20L, 
24L, 28L, 30L, 33L, 36L, 41L, 44L, 46L, 48L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 
13L, 15L, 18L, 23L, 26L, 29L, 31L, 35L, 38L, 41L, 46L, 47L, 2L, 
4L, 8L, 8L, 11L, 15L, 17L, 21L, 24L, 28L, 30L, 33L, 37L, 41L, 
45L, 46L, 49L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 15L, 19L, 23L, 27L, 29L, 
32L, 36L, 39L, 43L, 46L, 48L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 12L, 15L, 18L, 
21L, 24L, 28L, 30L, 33L, 37L, 41L, 45L, 46L, 50L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 
10L, 14L, 16L, 20L, 23L, 27L, 29L, 32L, 36L, 39L, 43L, 46L, 48L, 
3L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 12L, 15L, 18L, 21L, 25L, 28L, 31L, 34L, 38L, 
41L, 45L, 46L, 50L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 14L, 17L, 20L, 23L, 27L, 
29L, 33L, 36L, 40L, 43L, 46L, 48L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 15L, 
18L, 22L, 25L, 28L, 31L, 35L, 38L, 41L, 45L, 46L, 50L, 4L, 7L, 
8L, 11L, 14L, 17L, 20L, 24L, 28L, 30L, 33L, 36L, 41L, 43L, 46L, 
48L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 15L, 18L, 22L, 26L, 28L, 31L, 35L, 
38L, 41L, 46L, 47L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 11L, 14L, 17L, 20L, 24L, 
28L, 30L, 33L, 36L, 41L, 44L, 46L, 49L, 3L, 6L), AGE5 = structure(c(1L, 
5L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 
5L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 7L, 
2L, 9L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 
5L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 
7L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 
6L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 
6L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 
1L, 9L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 
7L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
9L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 7L), .Label = c("10-14", "15-19", "20-24", 
"25-29", "30-34", "35-39", "40-44", "45-49", "50-54"), class = "factor"), 
ZONA91OK = c(101L, 4079L, 712L, 8205L, 11022L, 14021L, 1714L, 
20067L, 2414L, 2810L, 300799L, 3305L, 36026L, 41024L, 4405L, 
4607L, 48015L, 308L, 610L, 8121L, 1006L, 1307L, 1511L, 1813L, 
2308L, 2605L, 2910L, 310799L, 35026L, 3811L, 411199L, 4601L, 
4708L, 202L, 405L, 8015L, 837L, 11033L, 1502L, 1702L, 2112L, 
2408L, 28047L, 30015L, 3305L, 3709L, 410199L, 4511L, 1202L, 
490699L, 3063L, 610L, 827L, 1006L, 1301L, 15036L, 1901L, 
2310L, 2709L, 29025L, 3201L, 36008L, 390899L, 4301L, 46184L, 
4805L, 206L, 504L, 817L, 813L, 12135L, 1519L, 1810L, 2104L, 
2402L, 28130L, 30030L, 3305L, 3707L, 411399L, 45165L, 46181L, 
5008L, 305L, 7026L, 803L, 1006L, 1413L, 16078L, 200999L, 
2312L, 2712L, 29069L, 3210L, 3616L, 391199L, 4313L, 46105L, 
4805L, 310L, 6153L, 8252L, 8205L, 1205L, 1505L, 1808L, 2110L, 
2508L, 2810L, 311399L, 3405L, 3807L, 41024L, 4507L, 46102L, 
500599L, 3014L, 706L, 8121L, 11028L, 14042L, 1712L, 20045L, 
2314L, 27031L, 29901L, 33024L, 3614L, 400199L, 4307L, 46021L, 
4805L, 3066L, 6153L, 8015L, 901L, 12040L, 1522L, 1806L, 2203L, 
2508L, 28047L, 311099L, 35004L, 3801L, 410199L, 4515L, 46017L, 
501199L, 407L, 7027L, 827L, 1102L, 1404L, 17155L, 200599L, 
24089L, 2812L, 30019L, 33024L, 3612L, 41038L, 4301L, 4628L, 
4805L, 307L, 6153L, 817L, 1004L, 1309L, 1508L, 1804L, 2206L, 
2606L, 28130L, 310799L, 35011L, 38022L, 411399L, 4622L, 4701L, 
1036L, 4079L, 807L, 803L, 1108L, 1410L, 1708L, 201399L, 2410L, 
28058L, 30043L, 33024L, 3610L, 410399L, 4401L, 4621L, 490499L, 
3059L, 6153L), VARIABLE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L), .Label = c("SPAIN_1998", 
"EU15DC_1998", "ROE_1998", "MAGREB_1998", "SSA_1998", "LA_1998", 
"ASIA_1998", "ROW_1998", "Total_1998", "SPAIN_1999", "EU15DC_1999", 
"ROE_1999", "MAGREB_1999", "SSA_1999", "LA_1999", "ASIA_1999", 
"ROW_1999", "Total_1999", "SPAIN_2000", "EU15DC_2000", "ROE_2000", 
"MAGREB_2000", "SSA_2000", "LA_2000", "ASIA_2000", "ROW_2000", 
"Total_2000", "SPAIN_2001", "EU15DC_2001", "ROE_2001", "MAGREB_2001", 
"SSA_2001", "LA_2001", "ASIA_2001", "ROW_2001", "Total_2001", 
"SPAIN_2002", "EU15DC_2002", "ROE_2002", "MAGREB_2002", "SSA_2002", 
"LA_2002", "ASIA_2002", "ROW_2002", "Total_2002", "SPAIN_2003", 
"EU15DC_2003", "ROE_2003", "MAGREB_2003", "SSA_2003", "LA_2003", 
"ASIA_2003", "ROW_2003", "Total_2003", "SPAIN_2004", "EU15DC_2004", 
"ROE_2004", "MAGREB_2004", "SSA_2004", "LA_2004", "ASIA_2004", 
"ROW_2004", "Total_2004", "SPAIN_2005", "EU15DC_2005", "ROE_2005", 
"MAGREB_2005", "SSA_2005", "LA_2005", "ASIA_2005", "ROW_2005", 
"Total_2005", "SPAIN_2006", "EU15DC_2006", "ROE_2006", "MAGREB_2006", 
"SSA_2006", "LA_2006", "ASIA_2006", "ROW_2006", "Total_2006", 
"SPAIN_2007", "EU15DC_2007", "ROE_2007", "MAGREB_2007", "SSA_2007", 
"LA_2007", "ASIA_2007", "ROW_2007", "Total_2007", "SPAIN_2008", 
"EU15DC_2008", "ROE_2008", "MAGREB_2008", "SSA_2008", "LA_2008", 
"ASIA_2008", "ROW_2008", "Total_2008", "SPAIN_2009", "EU15DC_2009", 
"ROE_2009", "MAGREB_2009", "SSA_2009", "LA_2009", "ASIA_2009", 
"ROW_2009", "Total_2009", "SPAIN_2010", "EU15DC_2010", "ROE_2010", 
"MAGREB_2010", "SSA_2010", "LA_2010", "ASIA_2010", "ROW_2010", 
"Total_2010", "SPAIN_2011", "EU15DC_2011", "ROE_2011", "MAGREB_2011", 
"SSA_2011", "LA_2011", "ASIA_2011", "ROW_2011", "Total_2011", 
"SPAIN_2012", "EU15DC_2012", "ROE_2012", "MAGREB_2012", "SSA_2012", 
"LA_2012", "ASIA_2012", "ROW_2012", "Total_2012", "NOTSPAIN_1998", 
"NOTSPAIN_1999", "NOTSPAIN_2000", "NOTSPAIN_2001", "NOTSPAIN_2002", 
"NOTSPAIN_2003", "NOTSPAIN_2004", "NOTSPAIN_2005", "NOTSPAIN_2006", 
"NOTSPAIN_2007", "NOTSPAIN_2008", "NOTSPAIN_2009", "NOTSPAIN_2010", 
"NOTSPAIN_2011", "NOTSPAIN_2012", "AFRICA_1998", "AFRICA_1999", 
"AFRICA_2000", "AFRICA_2001", "AFRICA_2002", "AFRICA_2003", 
"AFRICA_2004", "AFRICA_2005", "AFRICA_2006", "AFRICA_2007", 
"AFRICA_2008", "AFRICA_2009", "AFRICA_2010", "AFRICA_2011", 
"AFRICA_2012", "DWC_1998", "DWC_1999", "DWC_2000", "DWC_2001", 
"DWC_2002", "DWC_2003", "DWC_2004", "DWC_2005", "DWC_2006", 
"DWC_2007", "DWC_2008", "DWC_2009", "DWC_2010", "DWC_2011", 
"DWC_2012"), class = "factor"), FREQUENCY = c(614, 1943, 
59, 201, 188, 10859, 93, 
1494, 60, 1001, 1000, 689, 675, 934, 51, 
1240, 165, 13, 0, 14, 2, 2, 
2, 0, 3, 0, 40, 1, 18, 41, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 0, 
0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 11, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 5, 
64, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2173, 907, 9059, 839, 
4303, 100, 1727, 663, 694, 1210, 623, 
1261, 772, 697, 490, 1031, 490, 956, 704, 
1293, 1011, 739, 927, 755, 3340, 1190, 1254, 12880, 528, 
3244, 277, 892, 837, 1, 2, 10, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 8, 3, 
12, 0, 2, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 12, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 5, 2)), .Names = c("PROVINCE", "AGE5", "ZONA91OK", 
"VARIABLE", "FREQUENCY"), row.names = c(1L, 501L, 1001L, 1501L, 
2001L, 2501L, 3001L, 3501L, 4001L, 4501L, 5001L, 5501L, 6001L, 
6501L, 7001L, 7501L, 8001L, 8501L, 9001L, 9501L, 10001L, 10501L, 
11001L, 11501L, 12001L, 12501L, 13001L, 13501L, 14001L, 14501L, 
15001L, 15501L, 16001L, 16501L, 17001L, 17501L, 18001L, 18501L, 
19001L, 19501L, 20001L, 20501L, 21001L, 21501L, 22001L, 22501L, 
23001L, 23501L, 24001L, 24501L, 25001L, 25501L, 26001L, 26501L, 
27001L, 27501L, 28001L, 28501L, 29001L, 29501L, 30001L, 30501L, 
31001L, 31501L, 32001L, 32501L, 33001L, 33501L, 34001L, 34501L, 
35001L, 35501L, 36001L, 36501L, 37001L, 37501L, 38001L, 38501L, 
39001L, 39501L, 40001L, 40501L, 41001L, 41501L, 42001L, 42501L, 
43001L, 43501L, 44001L, 44501L, 45001L, 45501L, 46001L, 46501L, 
47001L, 47501L, 48001L, 48501L, 49001L, 49501L, 50001L, 50501L, 
51001L, 51501L, 52001L, 52501L, 53001L, 53501L, 54001L, 54501L, 
55001L, 55501L, 56001L, 56501L, 57001L, 57501L, 58001L, 58501L, 
59001L, 59501L, 60001L, 60501L, 61001L, 61501L, 62001L, 62501L, 
63001L, 63501L, 64001L, 64501L, 65001L, 65501L, 66001L, 66501L, 
67001L, 67501L, 68001L, 68501L, 69001L, 69501L, 70001L, 70501L, 
71001L, 71501L, 72001L, 72501L, 73001L, 73501L, 74001L, 74501L, 
75001L, 75501L, 76001L, 76501L, 77001L, 77501L, 78001L, 78501L, 
79001L, 79501L, 80001L, 80501L, 81001L, 81501L, 82001L, 82501L, 
83001L, 83501L, 84001L, 84501L, 85001L, 85501L, 86001L, 86501L, 
87001L, 87501L, 88001L, 88501L, 89001L, 89501L, 90001L, 90501L, 
91001L, 91501L, 92001L, 92501L, 93001L, 93501L, 94001L, 94501L, 
95001L, 95501L, 96001L, 96501L, 97001L, 97501L, 98001L, 98501L, 
99001L, 99501L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Honestly, I've never tried my function with 1.5M rows :( I'll look into it though.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. I hope the updated function is more convenient for you, and I'll consider updating the function in the package as well, or at least offering it as another alternative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(mydata)

dt[, `:=`(NATIONALITY = sub('(.*)_(.*)', '\\1', VARIABLE),
          YEAR        = sub('(.*)_(.*)', '\\2', VARIABLE))]
```

Comment: What does the '\\1' do exactly?

Comment: @Codoremifa it points to the regex match in the first set of parentheses

Comment: Sorry, bad phrasing. What I wanted to know is how does it work? The sub replacement parm is being set to '\\1', is it?

Comment: @Codoremifa the first `sub` replaces the expression matched by `(.*)_(.*)` by the expression matched in the first set of parentheses - which would be the nationality part (and the second `sub` replaces it with the second `(.*)` match, i.e. the year)

Comment: @RicardoSaporta unfortunately that wouldn't work, smth like this will though if one wants to go the `strsplit` route (and will likely be slower): `dt[, c('Nationality', 'Year') := as.data.table(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(VARIABLE), "_")))]`

Comment: Very nice, I didn't know that. Thanks. If I had a string like "Spain_1998_something1_something2_something3" I would have to use sub five times. Would `strsplit` be more efficient?

Comment: @Codoremifa I'm not sure at what point `strsplit` will become more efficient, but I'd switch to it if I had more than 2-3 `sub`'s for readability

Comment: If there is enough repetition, it should be worthwhile to do this with `by=VARIABLE`, right?

Comment: @Codoremifa, eddi, `strsplit` is not the slow party here (use `fixed=TRUE`). It's the `as.character(.)`. Load your `data.table` directly using `fread` and it'll be a character and then use `strsplit` with `fixed=TRUE` argument. Then `rbind` them and `cbind` them to your `data.table` and name them at the end. It should be faster.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like I need to look into updating my `concat.split` functions!

The version of the function that you tried to use makes use of `read.table`, which does tend to struggle with large datasets. I had used `read.table` because it has a convenient `text` argument that lets you specify a column in a `data.frame` as the input. This is really convenient when working with small-ish datasets, but evidently not with larger ones :)

As far as I can tell, `fread` from the "data.table" package doesn't have a similar feature, but since R tends to write files pretty quickly, I thought that it would be worth trying a similar approach as what I used in `concat.split` with `fread` instead of `read.table`.

Here's the concept:

1. Write the variable that needs to be split to a new file.
2. Use the blazing fast `fread` to read it back in.
3. Wait for `fread` to get a `text` argument somewhere down the line?

Here's that concept as a function (updated with edits as per @eddi's suggestions in the comments):

```
csDataTable <- function(dataset, splitcol, sep, drop = FALSE) {
  if (is.numeric(splitcol)) splitcol <- names(dataset)[splitcol]
  if (!is.data.table(dataset)) dataset <- data.table(dataset)
  if (sep == ".") {
    dataset[, (splitcol) := gsub(".", "|", get(splitcol), fixed = TRUE)]
    sep <- "|"
  }
  if (!is.character(dataset[[splitcol]])) {
    dataset[, (splitcol) := as.character(get(splitcol))]
  }
  x <- tempfile()
  writeLines(dataset[[splitcol]], x)
  Split <- fread(x, sep=sep, header = FALSE)
  setnames(Split, paste(splitcol, seq_along(Split), sep = "_"))
  if (isTRUE(drop)) dataset[, (splitcol) := NULL]
  cbind(dataset, Split)
}
```

Here's the function in action:

```
## Expand your sample data to 1.5 million rows to test
out <- mydata[rep(rownames(mydata), 1500000/nrow(mydata)), ]

csDataTable(out, "VARIABLE", "_")
#          PROVINCE  AGE5 ZONA91OK    VARIABLE FREQUENCY VARIABLE_1 VARIABLE_2
#       1:        1 10-14      101  SPAIN_1998       614      SPAIN       1998
#       2:        4 30-34     4079  SPAIN_1998      1943      SPAIN       1998
#       3:        7 50-54      712  SPAIN_1998        59      SPAIN       1998
#       4:        8 40-44     8205  SPAIN_1998       201      SPAIN       1998
#       5:       11 35-39    11022  SPAIN_1998       188      SPAIN       1998
#      ---                                                                    
# 1499996:       44 35-39     4401    ROE_1999         0        ROE       1999
# 1499997:       46 35-39     4621    ROE_1999         0        ROE       1999
# 1499998:       49 10-14   490499    ROE_1999         0        ROE       1999
# 1499999:        3 30-34     3059 MAGREB_1999         5     MAGREB       1999
# 1500000:        6 40-44     6153 MAGREB_1999         2     MAGREB       1999
```

---

In this test, at least, the solution fares much better than I expected:

```
subFun <- function() {
  dt = data.table(out)
  dt[, `:=`(NATIONALITY = sub('(.*)_(.*)', '\\1', VARIABLE),
            YEAR        = sub('(.*)_(.*)', '\\2', VARIABLE))]
} 
freadFun <- function() {
  csDataTable(out, "VARIABLE", "_")
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(subFun(), freadFun(), times = 20)
# Unit: seconds
#        expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#    subFun() 3.814174 4.244820 4.273834 4.345358 4.480520    20
#  freadFun() 1.356533 2.064262 2.152159 2.226465 2.300886    20
```

Comment: nice; you don't need the `eval`'s, just `(splitcol) := ...` will work and you might want to use `tempfile()`

Comment: @eddi, I've implemented your suggestions in the function and they have made the function more efficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is some solution with splitting factor labels

```
VARIABLE_LEVELS <- cbind("VARIABLE"=levels(mydata$VARIABLE),
                         as.data.frame(do.call("rbind",
                                       strsplit(levels(mydata$VARIABLE), split="_")))
mydata <- merge(mydata, VARIABLE_LEVELS)
#
# Insted of merege you can use VARIABLE (in mydata) as index
#
mydata <- cbind(mydata, VARIABLE_LEVELS[as.integer(mydata$VARIABLE),c("V1","V2")])
```