# Split a column of values delimited by colons into separate columns for each value

Tags: r, split, delimiter

I have a table of stings and numbers as below:

```
           V1                  V2
1  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:10,45:55:70:106,0,70
2  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:2,42:44:16:288,16,0
3  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:3,37:40:14:147,14,0
4  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:7,50:57:55:250,0,55
```

For vector `V2`, I would like to split the ':'- delimited (colon-delimited) values into separate columns for each value, *e.g.*:

```
   V1              V2   V3     V4  V5  V6
1  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1  10,45  55  70  106,0,70
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call that table `vcf`

```
vcf.info <- data.frame(t(sapply(vcf[,2], function(y) strsplit(y,split=":")[[1]])))
```

then `cbind` that with the original vcf column(s) that you want

```
vcf.info2 <- cbind(vcf[,1],vcf.info)
```

but in a real vcf I would

```
vcf.info2 <- cbind(vcf[,c(1,2,4,5,6,8,9)],vcf.info)
```

Something else you may find useful, in this case I am just getting the read depth, replace n with however many samples you have, and the 3 with 1 to 5 for GT,AD,DP,GQ,PL

```
selectReadDepth <- apply(vcf[,10:n],2,function(x) sapply(x, function(y) strsplit(y,split=":")[[1]][3]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `read.table` twice with 2 different separators:

```
txt = '           V1                  V2
1  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:10,45:55:70:106,0,70
2  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:2,42:44:16:288,16,0
3  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:3,37:40:14:147,14,0
4  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:7,50:57:55:250,0,55'

## here replace text=txt with your file name
dat <- read.table(text=txt,header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data.frame(x1=dat$V1,read.table(text=dat$V2,sep=':'))

              x1  V1    V2 V3 V4       V5
1 GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL 0/1 10,45 55 70 106,0,70
2 GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL 1/1  2,42 44 16 288,16,0
3 GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL 1/1  3,37 40 14 147,14,0
4 GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL 0/1  7,50 57 55 250,0,55
```

Comment: @Jeremy I don't get your point. Looks that you try to speak about a general case but it is not clear for me (at least the vcf format the way you describe it). You assume something that is not in the OP ( I can't guess that the OP has other columns)..Maybe You can add an example to your answer ...

Comment: yeah I know more about the data than the OP gave. It is two columns from a variant call file (vcf) obtained from aligning genetic sequence data to a reference and calling variants. Your solution works fine for the sample data given.

Comment: @Jeremy What I mean , it will be helpful and more interesting is if you provide the general fil format to adapt my solution ( even I don't see how it fails)

Comment: Oh right, this site has the first few lines of one: http://www.1000genomes.org/wiki/Analysis/Variant%20Call%20Format/vcf-variant-call-format-version-40

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it

```
data.frame(DF$V1, do.call(rbind, strsplit(DF$V2, split = ":", fixed = TRUE)))
##            DF.V1  X1    X2 X3 X4       X5
## 1 GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL 0/1 10,45 55 70 106,0,70
## 2 GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL 1/1  2,42 44 16 288,16,0
## 3 GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL 1/1  3,37 40 14 147,14,0
## 4 GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL 0/1  7,50 57 55 250,0,55
```

Answer (score 3):

I've included a family of functions called `concat.split` in my "splitstackshape" package, one of which is `concat.split.multiple`. Under the hood, it is like @agstudy's answer, but allows you to split multiple columns at once.

Usage is simple:

```
library(splitstackshape)
### Three required arguments: The input dataset,
###   a vector of the columns that need to be split up
###   (can also be the numeric column position), and the 
###   separator that should be used (can be different 
###   for each column).
concat.split.multiple(data = dat, split.cols = c("V2"), seps = ":")
#               V1 V2_1  V2_2 V2_3 V2_4     V2_5
# 1 GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1 10,45   55   70 106,0,70
# 2 GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1  2,42   44   16 288,16,0
# 3 GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1  3,37   40   14 147,14,0
# 4 GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1  7,50   57   55 250,0,55
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19231054/1270695) and [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6873058) for an idea for where the development of the function might be headed. The "data.table" variant will be much faster on larger datasets, but the data must be "rectangular" (that is, the resulting number of columns after the split must be balanced).