# Splitting columns in R

Tags: r, splitstackshape

I am new to R and I have a big dataset with 17 columns and over a 1m rows. I want to split one of the columns into 4 by divider '/'. It's taking forever for R to complete the below commands. Is there a better way of completing the below. I have given as much code info as possible and would appreciate any help.

```
sample2 <- read.csv("week1.csv", header=TRUE)
summ1 <- subset(sample2,select= -c(3,7), subset =(SPORTS_ID =='1'))
summ1 <- summ1[,-c(1)]
library(splitstackshape)
summ2 <- concat.split.multiple(summ1,2 , "/")
summ2 <- summ2[,-c(1,15)]
summ3 <- concat.split.multiple(summ2,14, "v")
write.csv(summm3, file="test.csv")
```

Comment: Sorry that should read one of the columns not rows I wasn to split

Comment: Without some sample data, it would be pretty hard to help.

Comment: Also, if the data are balanced, you'll probably want to ditch the basic `concat.split.multiple` approach and try the rewrite I was working on here: https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6873058

Comment: possible duplicate of [r data.frame create new variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228870/r-data-frame-create-new-variable)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strsplit`:

```
dat <- data.frame(a = c("a/b/c/d",
                        "e/f/g/h"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#         a
# 1 a/b/c/d
# 2 e/f/g/h

cbind(dat, do.call(rbind, strsplit(dat$a, "/")))
#         a 1 2 3 4
# 1 a/b/c/d a b c d
# 2 e/f/g/h e f g h
```

Comment: +1. I'd add a `fixed = TRUE` to your `strsplit` for efficiency. This fares quite decently in [the benchmarks I've posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22255113/1270695).

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, if your data are balanced (that is, you expect a nice rectangular dataset after splitting the data) you should look at my [**`concat.split.DT`**](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6873058) function.

Here are some tests.

#### Sven's data, but with 20K rows instead of 2

```
dat <- do.call(rbind, replicate(1e4, dat, simplify=FALSE))
dim(dat)
# [1] 20000     1
```

The "stringr" functions are likely to be a bit slow:

```
library(stringr)
system.time(do.call(rbind, str_split(dat$a,  "/")))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   3.194   0.000   3.211
```

But how do the other solutions fare?

```
fun1 <- function() concat.split.multiple(dat, "a", "/")
fun2 <- function() do.call(rbind, strsplit(dat$a, "/", fixed=TRUE))
## ^^ fixed = TRUE will make a big difference
fun3 <- function() concat.split.DT(dat, "a", "/")

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun1(), fun2(), fun3(), times = 10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
#  fun1() 530.46597 534.13486 535.19139 538.91488 553.61919    10
#  fun2()  30.22265  31.07287  31.81474  32.93936  40.28859    10
#  fun3()  22.57517  22.94169  23.10297  23.30907  31.97640    10
```

So, that's about half a second for the regular `concat.split.multiple` (which just uses `read.table` under the hood), and much better results for `strsplit` and `concat.split.DT` (the latter of which uses `fread` from "data.table" under the hood).

#### Let's scale it up even more, to 1 million rows now...

```
dat <- do.call(rbind, replicate(50, dat, simplify=FALSE))
dim(dat)
# [1] 1000000       1

microbenchmark(fun2(), fun3(), times = 5)
# Unit: seconds
#    expr      min       lq    median        uq       max neval
#  fun2() 6.257892 6.522199 13.728283 13.934860 14.277432     5
#  fun3() 1.671739 1.830485  2.203076  2.470872  2.572917     5
```

The advantage of the `concat.split.DT` approach is the convenience of splitting multiple columns with a simple syntax:

```
dat2 <- do.call(cbind, replicate(5, dat, simplify = FALSE))
dim(dat2)
# [1] 1000000       5
names(dat2) <- make.unique(names(dat2))
head(dat2)
#         a     a.1     a.2     a.3     a.4
# 1 a/b/c/d a/b/c/d a/b/c/d a/b/c/d a/b/c/d
# 2 e/f/g/h e/f/g/h e/f/g/h e/f/g/h e/f/g/h
# 3 a/b/c/d a/b/c/d a/b/c/d a/b/c/d a/b/c/d
# 4 e/f/g/h e/f/g/h e/f/g/h e/f/g/h e/f/g/h
# 5 a/b/c/d a/b/c/d a/b/c/d a/b/c/d a/b/c/d
# 6 e/f/g/h e/f/g/h e/f/g/h e/f/g/h e/f/g/h
```

Now, let's split all of them at once:

```
system.time(out <- concat.split.DT(dat2, names(dat2), "/"))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   6.260   0.040   6.532 
out
#          a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 a.1_1 a.1_2 a.1_3 a.1_4 a.2_1 a.2_2 a.2_3 a.2_4 a.3_1
#       1:   a   b   c   d     a     b     c     d     a     b     c     d     a
#       2:   e   f   g   h     e     f     g     h     e     f     g     h     e
#       3:   a   b   c   d     a     b     c     d     a     b     c     d     a
#       4:   e   f   g   h     e     f     g     h     e     f     g     h     e
#       5:   a   b   c   d     a     b     c     d     a     b     c     d     a
#      ---                                                                      
#  999996:   e   f   g   h     e     f     g     h     e     f     g     h     e
#  999997:   a   b   c   d     a     b     c     d     a     b     c     d     a
#  999998:   e   f   g   h     e     f     g     h     e     f     g     h     e
#  999999:   a   b   c   d     a     b     c     d     a     b     c     d     a
# 1000000:   e   f   g   h     e     f     g     h     e     f     g     h     e
#          a.3_2 a.3_3 a.3_4 a.4_1 a.4_2 a.4_3 a.4_4
#       1:     b     c     d     a     b     c     d
#       2:     f     g     h     e     f     g     h
#       3:     b     c     d     a     b     c     d
#       4:     f     g     h     e     f     g     h
#       5:     b     c     d     a     b     c     d
#      ---                                          
#  999996:     f     g     h     e     f     g     h
#  999997:     b     c     d     a     b     c     d
#  999998:     f     g     h     e     f     g     h
#  999999:     b     c     d     a     b     c     d
# 1000000:     f     g     h     e     f     g     h
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. You may need to adjust the regex patterns according to what your data contains. A reproducible example would help.
[How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

```
library(stringr)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x = seq(1,10,1), y = rep("first/second", 10)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
df$first <- str_replace(df$y, "\\/\\w+", "")
df$second <- str_replace(df$y, "\\w+\\/", "")
df

> df
    x            y first second
1   1 first/second first second
2   2 first/second first second
3   3 first/second first second
4   4 first/second first second
5   5 first/second first second
6   6 first/second first second
7   7 first/second first second
8   8 first/second first second
9   9 first/second first second
10 10 first/second first second
```

Comment: Sorry, but this would be a pretty bad idea for a few reasons. For starters, do you plan to do this if, say, you expected the result of the split to have 20 columns?

Comment: The original question stated that four new columns were expected. What are your other concerns?

Comment: Another concern is that "stringr" is not necessarily going to give you any speed boost. Not to mention that a good answer on SO is not necessarily one that solves an immediate problem as stated in the question, but one that might propose solutions that are applicable to a wider range of situations.

Comment: Hi Guys thanks for all the responses, I will try these out in awhile. A copy of the data column is below, i will be splitting into 4 new columns =                                                            English Soccer/Barclays Premier League/Fixtures 18 August/Arsenal v Sunderland

Comment: I want to break down the above into English Soccer for example in one column under column heading League, Barclays Premier league next column under Comp etc

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be working with characters and don't mind lists, `str_split` within the  `stringr` package should help

```
library(stringr)
x <- 'hello/hi/hey/hola'
str_split(x)
[[1]]
[1] "hello" "hi" "hey" "hola"
```

Comment: I was guessing ([and was able to verify](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22255113/1270695)) that this approach would not be very efficient. Using base R's string manipulation tools would be much more efficient.